yaml validation, All mapping items must start at the same column at line 14, column 1
I keep getting yaml validation errors for a part of my yaml that is not inteded to be yaml, but linux bash script,
(I'm trying to create a CloudFront template to start an EC2 isntance on AWS)
the error message is:

All mapping items must start at the same column at line 14, column 1

and it refers to the -y after yum update
Resources:
  MyInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-051f8a213df8bc089 
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: mydockertestKP
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - sg-12345678 
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          Fn::Sub |
            #!/bin/bash
            yum update -y
            yum install -y docker

            systemctl start docker

            curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
            chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

anyone knows what can I do to make the aws yaml validator to not treat the bash script as yaml ?
(VS2022 and yamllint.com show the same error)

The below should fix the issue.
Resources:
  MyInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-051f8a213df8bc089
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: mydockertestKP
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - sg-12345678
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          Fn::Sub: "#!/bin/bash yum update -y yum install -y docker systemctl start docker
            curl -L
            https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-c\
            ompose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
            chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose"


just added new line after #!/bin/bash

Looks like I needed to add a : after the Fn::Sub
